# In CSS/JS, how to word-wrap at every nth word?

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to add a paragraph to my web page but when I write, the text fills the full width of the screen.

```
<p>Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text </p>
```

I want, for example, to specify that only 25 words can fit on each line with css or JavaScript, before wrapping to next line.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: On the server which is generating the HTML, add a `<br>` every 25 words, or add a newline and specify formatting such as `white-space: pre` which preserves newlines. Or, write JS which does the same thing at the appropriate point in time in the life cycle of the page.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

you need to specify the p width or put it within a container that has a  defined width

```css
p.longtext {
    width:200px; 
}
```

```html
<p class='longtext'>Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text </p>
```

Comment: I don't get it--this doesn't answer the question. Why was it accepted?

Comment: @torazaburo :  I supposed that he doesnt want exactly  an x ( 25 in his example  ) number of words but he needs a way to control his paragraph width  and i guess my supposition was right since he accepted it . on the other hand , I agree with you my post  doesn’t literally answer the question (check the question before it got edited )

Answer (score 2):

It's difficult to wrap every 25 *words*, but you can set a specific width to wrap at:

```css
p {
    max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<p>Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text </p>
```

But, you can still do it every `n` words, it just might lead to inconsistencies as words can be different lengths:

```js
var p = document.getElementById("paragraph").innerText;

p = p.match(/(\S+ ){1,10}/g).join("<br>");

document.getElementById("paragraph").innerHTML = p;
```

```html
<p id="paragraph">Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text </p>
```

> **Note:** I've wrapped every 10 words, but you could just as easily wrap after as many words as you want, just replace the `10` in the match regex with `25`.

Answer (score 1):

This is actually surprisingly easy, I'd suggest wrapping at a certain width, but because you stated *specifically* you want to wrap every 25 words, here you go:

```js
Array.prototype.slice.call(document.querySelectorAll("p")).forEach(function(el) {
  el.innerHTML = el.innerText.match(/(\S+\s*){1,10}/g).join("<br>");
                                    //        ^^ 10 - number of words to wrap at
});
```

```html
<p>Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text Some long text</p>
```

Since 25 words is too wide for stack overflow, I wrapped at ten words instead, but you can do whatever.

Really, I wrote it across three lines, but it is just one line of JavaScript.